# Контроллер PHP Laravel работа с JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

у меня есть JSON массив который хранится в базе данных.
Как реализовать алгоритм `изменения/добавления/удаления` данных из этого массива в контроллере PHP фреймворка Laravel?
Сам массив выглядит вот так:

```
{
    "Me": {
        "Name": "Kirill",
        "Age": "24"
    },
    "Company": {
        "name": "Astra",
        "work": "Build"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну алгоритм прост.
1. Получаем значение `$json = $model->key;`;
2. Декодим его `$array = json_decode($json, 1);`;
3. Изменяем `$array['key'] = 'newVal';`;
4. Обратно кодируем `$json = json_encode($array, 1);`;
5. Сохраняем `$model->key = $json; $model->save();`.
Все...
Но чтоб этого не делать постоянно в модели где используете `json` для хранения, реализуйте метод - `updateJson($modelKey, $dataKey, $val);`
И все сведется к этому - `$model->updateJson('modelKey','dataKey', 'someValue');`.
Метод будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public function updateJson($modelKey, $dataKey, $val){
  $model = $this->toArray();
  $jsonData = json_decode($model[$modelKey], 1);
  $jsonData[$dataKey] = $val;
  $json = json_encode($jsonData, 1);
  $update = [];
  $update[$modelKey] = $json;
  $this->update($update);
}
```

Ну... остальные методы (удаление, добавление) сводятся к этому